# Fabric js Canvas text issue on iPhone

Tags: jquery, magento, fabricjs

I have developed an website for customizable invitation using Fabric JS and knockout JS on Magento community version. The invitation product working fine on Android and all windows/Mac version browsers but not on iPhone. As soon as all the fonts are loaded on iPhone text is broken in multiple line, overlapped and misplaced.

Website URL and product URL (click on personalized button):- http://candlebark.testingdemo.net/wedding-invitations/anchoredinloveweddinginvitation.html
Popup U/P:- test/test@123

The same product URL is working fine on iPhone simulator and on browser stack.

Comment: Please find the below screenshot URL for the issue on iPhone.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2585423/53dbaae3b74b7f965897c2f9d295001d

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2585427/ce200b1c2d2fbdc088a053c5c84ad84d

Answer (score 1):

It seems we had exactly the same issue:

- Misplaced text
- Strange ASCII-Icons instead of text on iPhone

I don't know if this is already fixed in the current 2.X build in our case we working with FabricJS 1.6.2 and wasn't able just to replace the main-framework behind our product, so I had to find out what's happening and find this:

Following issue only happened on `Safari for MAC and iPhone`, all other browsers worked fine:

A product editor, loads a predefined complex JSON file into the canvas and initializes then all his other functions.

**ISSUE 1: Misplaced Text**

> In our case, not the text was just misplaced, in fact while exporting the Canvas to JSON again, the "width" of the ITEXT-Objects got changed.
>
> After some research and experiments I found out that the `character-width` in edit-mode was miscalculated, which made the whole ITEXT-Object bigger after it got loaded.

---

And that's also the reason for the whole thing: `It seems that Safari loads, renders the web-fonts slightly different, which messed up the calculation for FABRICJS.`

**The solution in our case was easy:**

> 1. I created a function which checked the current browser.
> 2. Then a function which disabled font-preloading and initialization for Safari.
>
> *Now the editor loads everything fine again, only the target fonts are missing.*
>
> 3. When all is loaded and initialized, only then a AJAX-Call appends the Font-Header (Preload) and Font-Footer (Init) in Safari again.
> 4. It fires at the end a `canvas.renderAll();` with a slight timeout, and our product-motives looking same again (on the different browsers).

---

**ISSUE 2: Strange ASCII-Icons**

> The MAC Safari didn't had this problem, but on the iPhone there was sometimes these strange ASCII-Icons like in your screenshots. But in my case only aslong the target-font wasn't completly loaded and the canvas getting rendered. ( `canvas.renderAll();` )

---

Hope that helps and good luck!